# repetitively iterate array with specific number of iterations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am requesting stock data in JSONP format from an API. The response is an array with length 38.

*How could I repetitively iterate that array with a set number of iterations, i.e. for 58 total iterations: iterate from index 0 to 37 and again from index 0 to 19?*

(Practically, I would like to build a horizontal line of stock names like: printing all 38 stock names once and again appending the first 20 stock names once.)

Please see my code below. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
#gse-wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
.stocks {display: inline-block; width: 120px; text-align: center;}
#gse {animation-name: slide; animation-duration: 90s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; animation-timing-function: linear; white-space: nowrap;}
@keyframes slide {from {margin-left: 0px;} to {margin-left: -4560px;}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='gse-wrapper'><span id='gse'></span></div>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://dev.kwayisi.org/apis/gse/live?callback=?", function (data) { // API request for stock data
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function (i, value) { // iterating JSON array
$("#gse").append("<div class='stocks'>" + value.name + "</div>");
});
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `for-loop` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://dev.kwayisi.org/apis/gse/live?callback=?", function (data) {
    var data_slice = function(data, start, end) {
        var slice = data.slice(start, end);
        $.each(data, function (i, value) { // iterating JSON array
            $("#gse").append("<div class='stocks'>" + value.name + "</div>");
        });
    }
    data_slice(data, 0, 38);
    data_slice(data, 0, 20);
});
```

Comment: I just made a `data_slice` function so you wouldn't have to write the `$.each` loop twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 37; i++) { 
        // do something with myArray[i]
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) { 
        // do something with myArray[i]
    }
```

Comment: If the order is right, you could even do it in a single loop using a modulo: `for (i = 0; i < 58; i++) { // do something with myArray[i%38] }`

Answer (score 0):

> Use `for-loop` and mention `length` or condition in single `for-loop`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://dev.kwayisi.org/apis/gse/live?callback=?", function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
      $("#gse").append("<div class='stocks'>" + data[i].name + "</div>");
    }
    $("#gse").append("<hr>");
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      $("#gse").append("<div class='stocks'>" + data[i].name + "</div>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
 #gse-wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .stocks {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 120px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 #gse {
   animation-name: slide;
   animation-duration: 90s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
 @keyframes slide {
   from {
     margin-left: 0px;
   }
   to {
     margin-left: -4560px;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='gse-wrapper'><span id='gse'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a for loop with an outside variable for your maximum desired iterations 
and another variable to keep track of how many times you have iterated. Combine this with checks inside the for loop to see if you've finished the first loop, to start again, and to end when you've hit your max counter. E.g;

```
var max = 58 // Your desired looping amount
var current = 0;

for(var y = 0; y < max; y++){
  // Logic Here - data[y];

  if(y >= data.length){
    y = 0;
  }

  if(current == max){break;}

  current++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get your solution to work though. the console is telling me that x is not defined

Comment: My bad, that was an error whilst creating the solution. Change `x` for `max`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop in javascript and the modulo operator %.
This solution is in javascript with a javascript array.
To convert your json array to JavaScript, use:

```
 var array = JSON.parse(jsonArray);
```

If l is the length of your array and n is the preferred number of iterations, you could use something like this:

```
 for (x = 0; x < n; x++){
    array[x%l] // this is the element you can do stuff with
 }
```